# Get the bindingsource from a control

Tags: c#

I need a way to find the bindingsource that a control is bound to.
For example, when textbox1 is bound to bindingsource1
than I need a function with input textbox1 and it should return bindingsource1

example

```
textBox1..DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "name", true);

private BindingSource GetBS(Control something)
{
    return the bindingsource from Control
}
```

so when calling GetBS(textBox1) it should return bindingSource1

Anyone has some idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the BindingSource will not be found on the TextBox itself, but on a specific Binding, for example the "Text" Binding.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
        var source = textBox1.DataBindings["Text"].DataSource;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes before I can accept an answer

Comment: Hoohh.. hehe, didn't know that :)